# Can't get remote branches to local repo

Tags: git

Whenever I create a new branch in a remote repo, there is no way for me to get it to my local repo.

I've tried:

`git fetch --all`, which actually updates the remote branches, but they don't show up with `git branch`

`git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done` is the only thing that will work for me, but it grabs *all* branches that remote ever had. On large projects I end up getting upward of 100 branches from `git branch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch` only shows your local branches. Specify `-r` to show remote branches, or `-a` to show both local and remote branches.

To check out a local copy of a remote branch, run `git checkout <branch>` where `<branch>` is the name of the branch without the remote name prefix.

An example:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/foo
  remotes/origin/master
$ git checkout foo
Branch 'foo' set up to track remote branch 'foo' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'foo'
$ git branch -a
* foo
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/foo
  remotes/origin/master
$
```

You can read more about remote branches in [3.5 Git Branching - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book).

Answer (score 0):

Try `git branch -a` to list all branches (local and remote).

Then `git checkout YOUR_REMOTE_NAME/YOUR_BRANCH_NAME`, example `git checkout origin/dev`

Comment: That lists all of the remote branches, but as `remotes/remote-name/branch_name`. Any way to shorten this to just `branch_name`? My co-student's git works like that. they just `git fetch` and get all remote branhces as `branch-name`

Comment: `git checkout origin/dev` will cause you to end up with detached `HEAD`, which is probably not what was desired in this case. If you did this, get back to normal by simply checking out the previous branch using `git checkout -` or simply specifying the branch name, e.g. `git checkout master`.

Comment: Yes, just run `git checkout remote-name/branch_name` this will create a new local branch `branch_name`.